# Blender 'autosave' problems

Tags: linux

Blender's autosave function does not work properly for me, and never has. I am running Blender on Linux Mint 21.3. Maybe it's a Linux issue, I don't know. In preferences, I have set a path for the temporary files. I have set the autosave function to save every two minutes (while testing - in reality I'd ideally like every 15 or so). The result? I've been working on a scene all morning. Blender just crashed. No autosaves for this file except from two days ago.

I was thinking it is maybe a permission thing, but I don't think so, because I *do* still get the odd autosave when I am lucky, in the intended folder. This would not happen if the folder permissions were at fault.

If anyone has any ideas I'm all ears.

Nothing showing in console.

Thanks.

Comment: what Blender version?

Comment: Might it be that you work in sculpt or edit mode a lot? There is [a warning about that](https://i.postimg.cc/bYRcG0Tk/Screenshot-2.jpg)

Comment: Yes, but not this morning. Not once. Version 4.0.2. But I have tried many versions. Same issue.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you specified Blender's version. Is it the latest 4.0.2?

Comment: Yes, 4.0.2, as I mentioned just now. But it NEVER worked for any version.

Comment: Did you try using another folder? I think the problem might be in something the OS does or specific setup of the installation. The functionality has worked perfectly for me for around a decade with a whole bunch of versions and operating systems. How did you install it? Did you download it from Blender.org, or use some repository?